# Python Scatterplot Index Error

Tags: python

I can't determine why I am getting an index error for my scatterplot.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
colors=['b','r']  
for i in [2,4]:
    indices=np.where(benign_or_malignant==i)
    ax.scatter(clump_thickness[indices],single_ep_cell_size[indices], 
s=55,c=colors[i])
```

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 for i in [2,4]:
>         5     indices=np.where(benign_or_malignant==i)
>   ----> 6      ax.scatter(clump_thickness[indices],single_ep_cell_size[indices], 
>   s=55,c=colors[i])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

The dataset is formated like so (ct=clump_thickness, secs=single_ep_cell_size, cl=clump benign(2) or malignant(4):

```
id     ct   secs    cl<br>
1000025 5   2   2<br>
1002945 5   7   2<br>
1015425 3   2   2<br>
1016277 6   3   2<br>
1017023 4   2   2<br>
1017122 8   7   4<br>
1018099 1   2   2<br>
1018561 2   2   2<br>
1033078 4   2   2<br>
1035283 1   1   2<br>
1036172 2   2   2<br>
1041801 5   2   4<br>
```

As I understand it, it should plot clump thickness vs single ep cell size and color the points differently based on whether i = 2 or 4.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for name, group in df.groupby('cl'):
    ax.plot(group['ct'], group['secs'], marker='o', linestyle='', label=name, ms = 10)
ax.set(xlabel='clump thickness', ylabel='single ep cell size')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  How would I modify the code if the data is read from a csv file and stored in arrays?

 ids,clump_thickness,single_ep_cell_size,benign_or_malignant=_loadData()   #this is how you invoke the helper function.

Comment: Well the dataset looked like a Pandas dataframe to me. For plotting and grouping, I would recommend loading it into the dataframe first using pd.read_csv(yourfile)

Answer (score 1):

The list index error is referring to the `colors` list. `colors[i]` is not defined when `i` has value `4`.

A possible fix:

```
colors = ['b','r']
b_or_m = [2, 4]  
for i in [0, 1]:
    indices=np.where(benign_or_malignant==b_or_m[i])
    ax.scatter(clump_thickness[indices], single_ep_cell_size[indices], s=55, c=colors[i])
```